# Why doesa this try block create an indent error

Tags: python, indentation

Started learning python and trying to learn try blocks. However I am utterly confused to why this program creates an unident error (does not match other identation levels).

```
while True:
   try:
        yes=(int(input("how smart is neervesh")))
        if neervesh == 0:
            print("yes is smart")
        elif neervesh ==1:
            print("yeas")
        else:
            print("kill me now")
    except ValueError:
        print("dont be retarded like yes")
```

Comment: Get your IDE to show you whitespace, you've probably mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: The try: is only 3 spaces, but except is 4. Add the stack trace to the question so we can see which line is in error.

Comment: how do i get IDE to show whitespace

Comment: I figured this out by copy/paste of your code and running it to get the stack trace. It showed the `except` line and `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level` - so the problem was that try and except didn't have the same indents. If you add the actual stack trace to the question when you post it, we can spot these types of things without running it ourselves.

Comment: It depends on the IDE. Its typically under a `view` menu.

Comment: I fixed it , thanks guys

Comment: Seems like a prime candidate for 'simple typographical error' closure.

Answer (score 0):

Your `try` is indented by 3 spaces, your except by 4. You should stick to one indentation width (usually 4).

Answer (score -1):

I always use the program 'SublimeText'. This text editor gives you the possibility to change your indentation on the fly. You can either convert your indentation to tabs or spaces. This way, you'll likely prevent future 
 indentation errors.